# Accordion Menu CSS3, HTML5 problems with collapsing divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I have a problem with a accordion menu using HTML5 and CSS3. The accordion functions fine and has nice easing and transition. My problem is that I have alot of content for each content div and I need to use overflow-y to have the content scroll. If you scroll the content, then want to jump to another item...the div that you were just in collapses (as it should) but it doesn't revert back to the hyperlinked menu item, it shows the scrolled content instead.

I wanted to see if there are any suggestions on making this more navigational friendly when someone jumps to another item.

Here is an example. http://www.toolboxwebdesign.com/css3.html

**Thank you in advance for any help!**

Answer (score 0):

I would put a div around the content of the accordion, not including the title, and put your overflow-y on that div. That way the title will always be at the top and not scroll with the content.

Comment: Here is what I added .scroll
{
 overflow-y:scroll;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
} and I added the div.scroll to the content...there is just an empty scroll bar and I can't scroll the content. But I like your idea...it makes sense. I wonder why the content won't scroll? Here is what it looks like : http://www.toolboxwebdesign.com/css3.html

Comment: @toolbox3 - [This css3 accordion](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Accordion/index2.html) is worth a look. It works more like a conventional in that the head and body of each part of the accordion is separate. With this you could easily fix the height of body and give it a scrollbar for overflow.